# Faster way to load large Machine Learning Model saved in .rds file (R)

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a very large machine learning model that I have saved using the `saveRDS()` function. The total file size is over 300K+ KB and reading it into R takes 20+ seconds. Is there a faster way to load this file into R?

I did set `compression = FALSE`  and it did help a little.

Is there a library like `data.table` which is very fast when reading `.csv` and feather which is very fast when reading `.feather` files? I really appreciate any contributions.

Comment: How slow is slow to you? 20s is too slow?

Comment: @NelsonGon 20 secs is Very slow. We use this models to process 1000s of web request every day. We are looking for ways to call these models faster in other to process more web request.

Comment: Have you tried `fread`?! Sorry I know it's one of the fastest but maybe someone else will help answer.

Comment: @NelsonGon fread is from the data.table library. I have tried it and it does not seem to work with ML models saved in .rds.

Comment: @A.Suliman 367502376 bytes

Comment: Try using `saveRDS` with `compress = FALSE` options, that will help.

Comment: @PoGibas I have done that and I have not gotten any better increase in speed.

Comment: Your question is just too broad and you're asking for library recommendation. As far as I know currently in R there are no faster way to load more complicate objects. Also, this question has nothing to do with machine learning. Wish to help you, but doubt if that's possible.

Comment: @PoGibas I really appreciate your input. I specifically said ML models because some datasets can be stored as .rds files and fread will read those files easily. However, ML files stored as .rds cannot be read with fread. Once again, thank you for your input.

Comment: Like @PoGibas, I thought `saveRDS` with `compress = FALSE` should offer I/O benefits. Is there another bottleneck? Are you saving locally or to a network?

Comment: Have you thought about trying a different framework/programming language entirely? A 367MB file should probably not be read as frequently as you intend it to be read – it should be loaded once at the beginning of your service's deployment and persist in memory, providing predictions. Have you thought about exposing the model as some sort of web API? In Python, something like Flask or Falcon would be perfect for this (probably).

Comment: @blacksite That is a great idea but my concern with that is R is a single-thread language which implies that whenever a call is made to the API the model will still need to be loaded or read before using it.

Comment: Hence why I mentioned looking at a different framework/language entirely :)